# Dynamic calculation in SQL

Tags: sql, dynamic

I have the following data in a table in sql

```
             t1     t2       t3      t4
 01/11/2013  8087    8087   7752    7752
 01/12/2013  16705   14979  14972   14959
 01/01/2014  12933   12781  12781    x1
 01/02/2014  12273   12248   y1      x2
 01/03/2014  8155     z1     y2      x3
```

What I would like to do is populate the missing values x,y,z with the average differential of the actual values above multiplied by the previous value as in the calculations below.

```
z1 = 8155 * (sum(12781+12248)/ sum(12933+12273))

y1 = 12248 * (sum(14972+12781)/ sum(14979+12789))

y2 = z1 * (sum(14972+12781)/ sum(14979+12789))

x1 = 12781 * (sum(7752+14949)/ sum(7752+14972))

x2 = y1 * (sum(7752+14949)/ sum(7752+14972))

x3 = y2 * (sum(7752+14949)/ sum(7752+14972))
```

[Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEson.png)

The link hopefully will show the data in a clearer format if it does not appear clearly here. I could write a case statement but this table will grow and grow each month and wanted to know what would be the most efficient way to code this. 
Each month actual values would appear for the first missing value. So next month actual values for x1, y1, z1 will be present and the calculation will shift to the right one value. So the new calculation for y2 = z1 * ((12781+y1)/(12781+12248)). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: will it continue the same logic for next all rows? or this calculation is static only for this 5 rows?

Comment: This logic will continue going forward. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood correctly, but here you go, I think you are looking for query like below:

```
;with cte1 as (
    select startdate,
        t1, 
        t2 = case when row_number() over (order by startdate) > 4 then
            (t1*(z1param1+z1param2)/convert(float, z1param3+z1param4))
            else t2 end,
        a.x1param1, a.x1param2,
        b.y1param1, b.y1param2,
        c.z1param1, c.z1param2, c.z1param3, c.z1param4,
        t3,
        t4
        from #yourCalc cross apply
    (
    select t4 as x1param1, x1param2 = lead(t4) over(order by startdate)
    ,RowNa = row_number() over(order by startdate) from #yourCalc
    ) a
    cross apply (
    select t3 as y1param1, y1param2 = lead(t3) over(order by startdate)
    ,RowNb = row_number() over(order by startdate) from #yourCalc
    ) b
    cross apply (
    select t2 as z1param1, z1param2 = lead(t2) over(order by startdate)
    , t1 as z1param3, z1param4 = lead(t1) over(order by startdate),
    RowNc = row_number() over(order by startdate) from #yourCalc
    ) c
    where a.RowNa = 1
    and b.RowNb = 2
    and c.RowNc = 3
), cte2 as (
    select *,
    t31 = case when row_number() over (order by startdate) > 3 then
        (t2*(y1param1+y1param2)/convert(float, y1param1+y1param2))
        else t3 end
    from cte1)
, cte3 as (
    select *,
    t41 = case when row_number() over (order by startdate) > 2 then
        (t31*(x1param1+x1param2)/convert(float, x1param1+x1param2))
        else t4 end 
        from cte2)
    select startdate, t1, t2, t31 as t3, t41 as t4 from cte3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. When I try to run your code I get an error saying 'lead is not a recognized built in function name. I'm running Navicat on a mac machine.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: navicat version 11.2.13 premium

Comment: Provide me the sql server version

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 (X64)

Comment: Oops lead/lag introduced only from SQL Server 2012... You need to do subquery of alternate to lead by joining same table(self join) by row_number() + 1 which will give lead value

Comment: Thanks for your help, I used your code structure to get what I needed.